# Reload a scene in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I made ​​a flash game with ActionScript 3. I want when the character falls into water or swamp
or his score=0, the game to be start from first.
I want load **scene** from first.
I am a beginner in as3. Please help me by details.
But I do not know what code to write.
I'm grateful for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I can only suggest grouping your level dependent variables and writing your own reset() method that is used to initialise and start the game. Then calling that whenever one of the loss conditions are met to restart the game.

As far as I know, this may not always be a quick and clean thing to do, nor do I know of any single "one size fits all" solution that won't causing any further problems down the line. This is more to do with how your design and layout your game code.